# How to apply RGB filter in kineticjs?

Tags: kineticjs

i want remove Red, Green and Blue contribution from kinticjs drawn image, With help of this link http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-grayscale-image-tutorial/
 gray-scale conversion working good, similarly i need to filter Red, Green and Blue separately.

I am using this kineticjs files
kinetic-v5.0.1.js
kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js

I have to know how to do this.
Please advice Me. Waiting for your reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image.filters([Kinetic.Filters.RGB]);
image.blue(50);
image.red(100);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/joruw/1/edit)

Comment: Hi, How to Remove all Filters from image when reset button clicked.

Comment: `image.filters([]); layer.draw();`